# MySQL sort images by most viewed

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have an images table which stores an image id, title, the user who uploads it, a timestamp and file extension.

I also have a views table which records when an image has been viewed. the columns are id, image id, timestamp and the user who viewed the image.

What i need and have no idea how to do is to run an SQL query which will return a set of images in order of the most viewed.

I've been looking around on here and Google but just don't know what to actually search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT images.*, count(views.view_id) view_count
FROM images
LEFT JOIN views on views.image_id = images.image_id
GROUP BY images.image_id
ORDER BY view_count DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a669b/5

The GROUP BY clause tells the "aggregate functions" (count, sum, min, max, etc) how to behave. In this case, we are grouping by image and grabbing the count of views per image. `COUNT` only count non-null values, and we don't want to count the views that don't exist, so we're keying off `views.view_id`.

If you do an INNER JOIN rather than a LEFT JOIN, it will only return the images which have views. The LEFT JOIN allows us to get counts of zero.

Comment: this isn't coming up with any results :/ I feel i should explain that each row in the views table counts for one view of an image

Comment: This should do exactly that. Are the table names and column names right? I just took a wild guess at the actual names.

Comment: yeah everything is named correctly as far as i can see. although view_count is not a name in my database, does that matter?

Comment: `view_count` is the name we are giving to the result of `count(*)`.

Comment: I've edited to reflect that `count(views.view_id)` is correct rather than `count(*)`

Comment: If your column name is actually `image id` like you say in your question, and not `image_id`, then you need to wrap that in backticks. Like this `\`image id\`` where I had `image_id`. But it's generally (always) a bad idea to have spaces in column names.

Comment: to be fair the column is actually just id but ive changed my query to reflect that and im still getting nothing back :/ not even and mysql num rows result

Comment: ok so ive just put mysql error in and its returning this: :  mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: That line should look like: `mysql_query('SELECT ...');`, but it sounds like you're sending an array into it.

Comment: ok i think i know what the problem is. i'm calling in the query as a variable but when i put it in as a string it's fine

Comment: If you need help building the query variable, please put that in a new question. I hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be looking at joins, join the images table to the images viewed table, then you can run one query across both tables.